# How to get the action from the HttpServlet request to dispatch to multiple pages

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, dispatcher

I am using the Page Controller pattern. How could I use the same controller for two different pages by detecting the request action and then dispatching according to the result?

Here is my code:

**account.jsp**

```
<form name="input" action="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/edit" method="get">
   <input type="submit" value="Modifier" />
</form>
```

**Account Servlet**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("received HTTP GET");

        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action == null)
        {
            // the account page
            dispatch(request, response, "/account");    
        }
        else if (action == "/edit") {
            // the popup edit page
            dispatch(request, response, "/edit");
        }

        protected void dispatch(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, String page)
            throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(page);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
    }
```

Comment: What is the code for `doExecute` and `dispatch`?

Comment: Please ignore `doExecute` and I have added the `dispatch` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "request action"?

Comment: @Ramesh, suppose you have a controller for `http://localhost:8080/myproject/edit` and `http://localhost:8080/myproject/account`. Those are two different actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found out that using [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath%28%29) gets exactly what I needed so I don't need to parse anything!

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("received HTTP GET");

    String action = request.getServletPath();

    if (action.equals("/account"))
    {
        // the account page
        dispatch(request, response, "/content/account.jsp");    
    }
    else if (action.equals("/edit")) 
    {
        // the popup edit page
        dispatch(request, response, "/content/edit.jsp");
    }
}

protected void dispatch(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, String page)
        throws javax.servlet.ServletException, java.io.IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(page);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the answer for the question you have asked. You wanted to know path in a Generic controller. getServletPath() returns only if have servlet mapping.

Comment: This is exactly the solution to the question above. Of course you have to add the mapping to the web.xml file, as you would get a 404 if you don't, and that's the whole point of having a page controller, or else I would of opted for a front controller instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `httpServletRequest.getPathInfo()` .

**This is what the Documentation says:**

```
java.lang.String getPathInfo()

Returns any extra path information associated with the URL the client sent when it
made this request. The extra path information follows the servlet path but 
precedes the query string and will start with a "/" character.

This method returns null if there was no extra path information.

Same as the value of the CGI variable PATH_INFO.

Returns:
    a String, decoded by the web container, specifying extra path information that
    comes after the servlet path but before the query string in the request URL; 
    or null if the URL does not have any extra path information
```

In your case, if the `AccountServlet` is mapped to `/accounts/*` it gives the value like this:

- For url `/accounts/account` it returns `/account`
- For url `/accounts/edit` it returns `/edit`

Comment: interesting. I will have to try this out. So far I was getting the URI doing `request.getRequestURI().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to have a look to `request.getRequestURI()` and then obtain the last part of that URI:

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI().getPath();
String action = uri.substring(0, uri.lastIndexOf('/'));
...
```

I haven't checked this code. Be careful with edge cases.

I'm not sure if I understood your question. Hope this helps, anyway.